# How to pass a variable from another function to the view in index function

Tags: json, laravel, function, laravel-5, view

I want to pass the `$data` variable from the `findCity()` function with the json return to the view in the index function.

How can I do that please ?

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{  
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $countries = Location::select('country_name')
            ->groupBy('country_name', 'country_name')
            ->get();

        $cities = Location::select('city_name','city_name')
            ->where('region_name', $request->region_name)
            ->groupBy('city_name', 'city_name')
            ->get();

        $areas = Area::get()->toTree();

        return view('home', compact('areas','countries', 'cities'));
    }

    public function findCity(Request $request)
    {
        $data = Location::select('city_name','city_name')
            ->where('region_name', $request->region_name)
            ->groupBy('city_name', 'city_name')
            ->get();

        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

The Ajax code :

```
$(document).on('change','.regionName',function(){

    //console.log("hmm its change");

    var cat_id=$(this).val();

    //console.log(cat_id);

    var div=$(this).parent();

    var op=" ";

    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url:'{!!URL::to('findCityName')!!}',
        data:{'region_name':cat_id},
        success:function(data){

            //console.log('success');

            //console.log(data);

            //console.log(data.length);

            op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>Choose City</option>';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

            op+='<option value="{{ route('user.location.store', $cities) }}">'+data[i].city_name+'</option>';

           }


        div.find('.cityName').html(" ");

        div.find('.cityName').append(op);


        },
        error:function(){

        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `findCity()` to be an static method and call it from inside the `index()` method:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // The rest of your code here...

    // Calling the static method
    $city = self::findCity($request);

    return view('home', compact('areas', 'countries', 'cities', 'city'));
}

public static function findCity(Request $request)
{
    $data = Location::select('city_name', 'city_name')
        ->where('region_name', $request->region_name)
        ->groupBy('city_name', 'city_name')->get();

    return $data;
}
```

Read more about [static methods in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.methods).

Comment: I tried it but ajax function in the url responsed but with headers: HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date @Camilo

Comment: Add more info to your question. You didn't mention no AJAX call. Which controller method is being call with AJAX? What are the parameters?

Comment: it's so long code I am not sure how to put it all here ,, but i have a County and regions and cities table in database and i made a drop down that get cities and regions names from server and update the URL with the city you choose and that was the Ajax response i had

Comment: Don't need to add all of your code, just the relevant parts to reproduce your problem. Without it I won't be able to help you further.

Comment: Add the code to your original question by editting it. Do not add it as an answer.

Comment: I just edited it ,, sorry i am kinda new to Stackoverflow

Comment: Still is not clear what you are trying to do, try improving your question. A response with a 200 status code is expected when no errors occurred.

Comment: I think this should be in a different post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993284/dynamic-dropdown-with-ajax-from-one-table-in-laravel I posted it

Answer (score 0):

You need to call,pass and return using a function. like this one. I think it can help you.

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{  
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $countries = Location::select('country_name')
            ->groupBy('country_name', 'country_name')
            ->get();

        $cities = $this->findCity($request)

        $areas = Area::get()->toTree();

        return view('home', compact('areas','countries', 'cities'));
    }

    public function findCity($request)
    {
        $data = Location::select('city_name','city_name')
            ->where('region_name', $request->region_name)
            ->groupBy('city_name', 'city_name')
            ->get();

        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but ajax function in the url responsed but with headers: HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date